# Adding a Date into a Table TSQL using Weighting

Tags: t-sql

I have a Site Table where each site has a Rating between 1 and 4, I also have a capacity table where I want to add a start date using the rating from the site table, for example

A site with a rating of 1 the Start Date should be 01/05/2010 and a End Date 30/09/2010
A site with a rating of 2 and 3 the Start Date should be 01/04/2010 and a End Date 01/11/2010
A site with a rating of 4 the Start Date should be 01/01/2010 and a End Date 31/12/2010

I have had help with the first two columns already see code below, I now need to add the start date and end date. Can you help?

```
USE OCCUPANCY
CREATE TABLE Cap1
(PitchType_Skey int, 
 Site_Skey int)

DECLARE @PitchType_Skey INT
DECLARE @Site_Skey INT


SET @PitchType_Skey = 1
SET @Site_Skey = 1


WHILE (@Site_Skey < 127)

BEGIN
    IF @PitchType_Skey = 8

BEGIN
   SET @PitchType_Skey = 1
   SET @Site_Skey = @Site_Skey + 1
END

    IF (@Site_Skey < 127)

BEGIN
     INSERT INTO dbo.Cap1 (PitchType_Skey, Site_Skey)
     SELECT @PitchType_Skey, @Site_Skey
END

  SET @PitchType_Skey = @PitchType_Skey + 1

END
```

Answer (score 0):

In one command and using ISO dates

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Cap1 (PitchType_Skey, Site_Skey, StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Site_Skey),
   Site_Skey /*from site table column*/,
   CASE rating
      WHEN 1 THEN '20100501'
      WHEN 4 THEN '20100101'
      ELSE '20100401'
   END,
   CASE rating
      WHEN 1 THEN '20100930'
      WHEN 4 THEN '20101231'
      ELSE '20101101'
   END
FROM Site
```